# javascript turned off help

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a small application where I am displaying some text wrapped in 3 divs so I am actually displaying 1 div at a time also there are prev and next buttons for users to toggle between the div's. Now when javascript is turned off i just want to display 1 div without the prev and next buttons. I have and idea that it can be done with javascript by manipulating the CSS like.

```
document.getelementbyid("id1").style.display="visible";
document.getelementbyid("id1").style.display="none";
```

Thanks

Comment: Think this through a bit. If JavaScript is *turned off* how do you expect to *use JavaScript* to manipulate the CSS..? **Also** you've asked six questions that I can see so far, and accepted no answers. A 0% accept-rate isn't much of an incentive to offer help.

Comment: yup thats true never thought of that. may be atleast if we can alter the CSS?

Comment: Can you use a server side language? If so, which one?

Comment: nope...we cant ... we just need to alter the css contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set those div's to display:none; (in CSS) by default, add id for both, and after page load set document.getelementbyid(..).style.display="visible"; (in JavaScript)

PS. u could use jquery or other, will be much more easy ;)

try this:

```
[style]#prev, #next { display:none; }
[js]
function showButtons()
{
    document.getElementById('next').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('prev').style.display="block";
}
[html]
body onload="showButtons()">
div id="next">next..
div id="prev">prev..
```

This way without JS prev/next wont be displayed, and with JS they will show after page loads.

Comment: Important to note that this code would have the divs (non scripted and scripted) hidden until the entire page content has finished rendering (including downloading of all images, flash content, etc), resulting in a delay before the content is visible and the layout would likely be shifted around when the divs are shown.

Comment: Toggling an element between hidden and visible isn't that difficult. Loading such as massive library as jQuery for such a simple manipulation would be ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `<noscript>` tag to both define the styles of the scripted elements and display your alternate div instead:

```
<noscript>
  <style type="text/css">
    #scripted-div1, #scripted-div2, #scripted-div3 { display:none; }
  </style>
  <div>
    <!-- Alternate content goes here -->
  </div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Firefox with NoScript will ignore javascript and also ignore stuff within `<noscript>` tags. (I've not actually tested that, but I'm pretty sure.)

Answer (score 1):

Arrange your default page view as it would be displayed with javascript turned off, and then, if it is on, you will be able to add desired elements into desired positions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set the style inside a `noscript` tag.

Also, perhaps you should accept previous answers and respect the answers other have given you.

Comment: yup i just missed to accept it actually new to SO. i did it thanks for letting me know.